# What exactly is a REST API in reference to Docker?

Tags: api, docker

AFAIK, APIs are a means by which two computers communicate with each other.
What exactly is REST API?

[image]

My confusion arises from this figure where a docker cli which is on the same host as the docker daemon requires REST API to communicate with each other. Isn't that weird? Why'd you need REST API to communicate in a same host in same network? Maybe I am misunderstanding the point. Someone explain how does the need of REST API comes in docker?

Comment: FWIW docker's design does cause some problems, which is why these days we have the option of daemonless container engines such as podman, in which a container is actually a child of the process that runs it, rather than of a separate system-wide daemon. You can still have a management API, but you don't actually *need* to.

Comment: Originally, API = Application Programming Interface. If anything, it's more of a means by which *programmers* communicate :) The horrible vicissitudes that later butchered the concept beyond recognition are alas typical of our industry.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a good question and you could similarly ask why a locally installed [IDE is built on top of a web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29966093/what-is-the-visual-studio-code-editor-built-on).

I think the root answer lies in the increasing connectivity to and reliance upon the web in software.  The distinction between local and remote is being abstracted away over time due to that trend.  Consider how you would manage a remote container.  You would need some sort of networked interface and REST is an obvious choice for that.

If we change the question from 'why do I need REST a local API?' but rather: 'what kind of API works in both a local and networked context?' I think the reason for this becomes more obvious.

Answer (score 5):

An API is a means by which two computers communicate. Also two programs. Also two modules. Also two objects. Also two functions. Also ...

> Why'd you need REST API to communicate in a same host in same network?

You don't. But since you have the REST API you don't care. Just use the loopback address and you can talk to yourself. Sure it feels like driving your car to your mail box but it works. And if they move your mailbox down the street you don't have to change your routine that much.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of docker, the daemon has significantly higher privileges than the CLI, so the API helps to enforce that separation. It also allows you to have the CLI and daemon on separate machines if you want. This has security implications, so it's not common in production, but is occasionally useful in situations like CI testing.